# Как поменять цвет рамки окна?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, framelesswindowhint

Когда окно в фокусе, то появляется синяя рамка вокруг окна.

Когда не в фокусе ее нет.

Как поменять цвет или вообще убрать ее? 
У меня 10 винда если что.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня прям день сурка с вами :) Рамка как и titlebar окна рисуется оконным менеджером операционной системы, поэтому или менять тему, или самому рисовать рамку, предварительно убрав рамку оконного менеджера

Comment: Ну почему все так сложно....

Comment: Опять заморочки)

Comment: В другом вопросе вам уже давали пример кастомного оконного виджета, допилите его, чтобы рамку рисовало :) я кст, немного подпилил: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/b90e1f73191e95b9295a1f97632babba9f839ad3/FOO_TEST_TEST/pyqt__custom_title_bar

Comment: Интересные советы здесь люди дают. Убрать системную рамку и самому рисовать свою кастомную? Anki тоже на python и Qt сделан. И рамка там чёрная, и вроде бы, чуть тоньше системной. Тоже кастомная? Я tkinter изучаю. Там сделать свою рамку не сложно. Придётся слегка поднапрячь свою лень. Ради тёмной темы.
Вот референс, если кому интересно: https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-tasks/thread3090463.html#post17255761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно говорит @gil9red и пример уже рассматривали. Но в том примере много текста.

Вкратце создание окна без полей, которое можно перетаскивать может выглядеть так:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)    # Создает окно без полей.
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.old_pos = None

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(" Перетаскиваем окно, Созданное без полей.", self))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Закрыть окно", self, clicked=self.close))

    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):         
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    # вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `parent` можно не заполнять, если виджеты будут добавлены в компоновщик: QLabel("...", self) -> QLabel("..."), это касается всех виджетов. Мне кажется, что это избыточность. И, думаю, что лучше явно указывать компоновщик для виджета: `self.setLayout(layout)`, чем через аргумент parent'а

Answer (score 2):

Как в комментарии писал, нужно самому рисовать. В этом поможет `paintEvent` и желательно `Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground` – он обеспечит прозрачность фона и возможность закрасить его, что упрощает задачу:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.old_pos = None
        self.frame_color = Qt.darkCyan

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Перетаскиваем окно, созданное без полей."))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Закрыть окно", clicked=self.close))

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return

        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        painter.setBrush(Qt.white)
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.frame_color, 10))

        painter.drawRect(self.rect())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** дополнительно можно менять цвет рамки, например, когда мышка попадает на окно и уходит с него:

```
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.frame_color = Qt.darkCyan
        self.update()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.frame_color = Qt.darkGreen
        self.update()
```

Comment: Просто гениально. Ну вот это другое дело. Огромное спасибо вам. Тут хоть разобраться можно)