# Как размыть задний фон за окном?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, blur

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задний фон за окном размывается. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: А где видите-то?

Comment: Так-то размытие есть ещё с Windows Vista, странно что первый раз видите)

Comment: Ну я чет не видел чтоб так именно было)

Comment: Именно как "так"?

Comment: Этот эффект называется `blur`.

Comment: А как этот эффект реализовать? На pyqt5 желательно.

Comment: @LLENN blur эффект - это когда всё изображение размытое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дальше будет видна прогрессия решения, поэтому если не интересно, переходи в конец ответа.

---

Это конечно не `blur`, но похоже :)

Берем код из [предыдущего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/858124/201445) и при рисовании фона к RGB добавляем прозрачность:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QColor


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.old_pos = None
        self.frame_color = Qt.darkCyan

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Закрыть окно", clicked=self.close))

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return

        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 200))
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.frame_color, 10))

        painter.drawRect(self.rect())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD.**

Кое-что получилось, но это благодаря оконному менеджеру – он нарисовал, поэтому если убрать рамку не будет работать:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Закрыть окно", clicked=self.close))

        self.setLayout(layout)

        from ctypes import windll, c_int, byref
        windll.dwmapi.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(c_int(self.winId()), byref(c_int(-1)))
```

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD.**

Можно попробовать еще метод [DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmenableblurbehindwindow) – написал я.

Это было непросто, но зацепка с тем методом помогла и нашел идеальное решение:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, HRGN
from ctypes import windll, c_bool, c_int, POINTER, Structure
from ctypes import WINFUNCTYPE


class DWM_BLURBEHIND(Structure):
    """
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    """
    _fields_ = [
        ('dwFlags', DWORD),
        ('fEnable', c_bool),
        ('hRgnBlur', HRGN),
        ('fTransitionOnMaximized', c_bool)
    ]


prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, POINTER(DWM_BLURBEHIND))
params = (1, "hWnd", 0), (1, "pBlurBehind", 0)
_DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow = prototype(("DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow", windll.dwmapi), params)

# Before we get started, see if we have the DWM functions.
has_dwm = hasattr(windll, 'dwmapi') and hasattr(windll.dwmapi, 'DwmIsCompositionEnabled')


# SOURCE: https://github.com/stendec/siding/blob/master/siding/_aeroglass.py
def DWM_enable_blur_behind_window(widget):
    DWM_BB_ENABLE = 0x0001

    bb = DWM_BLURBEHIND()
    bb.fEnable = c_bool(True)
    bb.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE
    bb.hRgnBlur = None

    # NOTE: с WA_TranslucentBackground клики проходят сквозь окно
    # widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)

    result = _DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(c_int(widget.winId()), bb)

    return not result


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        DWM_enable_blur_behind_window(self)

        self.old_pos = None
        self.frame_color = Qt.darkCyan

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Закрыть окно", clicked=self.close))

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return

        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD.**

А если нужна рамка? Как всегда – добавляем `paintEvent` и рисуем:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self)

    painter.setBrush(Qt.transparent)
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.darkCyan, 10))

    painter.drawRect(self.rect())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD.** Предыдущий код с `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` похоже на Win10 не работает, но при поиске аналогов, была найдена недокументированная функция [SetWindowCompositionAttribute](http://undoc.airesoft.co.uk/user32.dll/SetWindowCompositionAttribute.php), которая не заработала у меня на Win7, но заработала на Win10.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, ULONG
from ctypes import windll, c_bool, c_int, POINTER, Structure


class AccentPolicy(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('AccentState', DWORD),
        ('AccentFlags', DWORD),
        ('GradientColor', DWORD),
        ('AnimationId', DWORD),
    ]


# SOURCE: http://undoc.airesoft.co.uk/user32.dll/GetWindowCompositionAttribute.php
class WINCOMPATTRDATA(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('Attribute', DWORD),
        ('Data', POINTER(AccentPolicy)),
        ('SizeOfData', ULONG),
    ]


# SOURCE: http://undoc.airesoft.co.uk/user32.dll/SetWindowCompositionAttribute.php
# BOOL WINAPI SetWindowCompositionAttribute (
#     HWND hwnd,
#     WINCOMPATTRDATA* pAttrData
# )
SetWindowCompositionAttribute = windll.user32.SetWindowCompositionAttribute
SetWindowCompositionAttribute.restype = c_bool
SetWindowCompositionAttribute.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(WINCOMPATTRDATA)]


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)

        # SOURCE: http://howtucode.com/c-pinvoke-user32dll-getwindowcompositionattribute-13192.html
        accent_policy = AccentPolicy()
        accent_policy.AccentState = 3  # ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND;

        win_comp_attr_data = WINCOMPATTRDATA()
        win_comp_attr_data.Attribute = 19  # WCA_ACCENT_POLICY
        win_comp_attr_data.SizeOfData = ctypes.sizeof(accent_policy)
        win_comp_attr_data.Data = ctypes.pointer(accent_policy)

        hwnd = c_int(self.winId())
        ok = SetWindowCompositionAttribute(hwnd, ctypes.pointer(win_comp_attr_data))
        print(ok)

        print(ctypes.get_last_error())

        self.old_pos = None
        self.frame_color = Qt.darkCyan

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Закрыть окно", clicked=self.close))

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return

        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не, не похоже, банальная прозрачность и в Windows XP без проблем делалась

Comment: @andreymal, а как вам это? :)

Comment: А вот это неплохо :)

Comment: Неплохое вышло развлечение :) Жаль, этот труд скорее всего, в основном, автора вопроса и оценит

Comment: И как вам это только и удается? Потрясающе. Спасибо за проделанную вами работу. Жаль только чет последний метод не работает у меня, хотя и винда последняя.

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov, не работает DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow? У вас 10-ка стоит?

Comment: Ага. Самая последняя.

Comment: [Похоже DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow  не работает](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/183488-_winapi_dwmenableblurbehindwindow-in-windows-10/) для win10. По ссылке упоминается метод SetWindowCompositionAttribute

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov, попробуйте: https://pastebin.com/2G6P9eye У меня не сработало, возможно потому что у меня win7, а не потому что код неправильный :)

Comment: Проблема исчерпана. Все работает. Спасибо за все)

Comment: У вас заработал вариант с SetWindowCompositionAttribute? О_О

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov?

Comment: Ну вроде бы да.

Comment: Это круто :) Тогда, я добавляю этот вариант в ответ. Просто, у меня не было возможности проверить тот код

Answer (score 1):

Дополню для тех, кто в будущем забредёт на эту страничку. [@gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/858167/217579) использует в своём решении метод:

```
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
```

Это приводит к тому, что фон окна не очищается, при изменении содержимого и вызове события **paintEvent**, из-за этого полупрозрачные элементы окна рисуются друг на друге множество раз и в итоге становятся непрозрачными, например тот же antialising у текста. Вместо этого советую использовать:

```
self.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
```